# Close question after some days of acceptance (if user accept the answer)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, accepted-answer

I get disturbed by an answer for a question posted by me, if I did accept and confirm an answer a couple of months ago. I better suggest you to close/mark the question as "no more answers needed".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am **very strongly against this**.

The whole point of a Q/A site is to generate useful questions and answers. Where would we be if we didn't allow answers to perfectly valid questions anymore?

If you don't need any more answers, ignore it, but there might always be a *better* answer that is not only useful to you, but all the others reading.

Don't forget that most of the site's traffic comes from search engines. People might have different expectations and having alternative solutions or workarounds is always good (and *never* something we should preemptively discourage by closing a question).